# Детекция доступа к памяти процесса стороннего приложения, Windows

Tags: windows, память, code-injection

Предположим есть процесс A и процесс B, который хочет прочитать и/или записать что-либо в память А.(ОС Windows) Какими способами процесс А может отследить, что сторонний процесс пытается читать и/или писать в его память, и соответственно как избежать обнаружения для процесса B? (т.е. иными словами можно ли читать память стороннего процесса так, чтобы это никак нельзя было обнаружить?) Если можно - максимально подробно.

И второй вопрос - правильно ли я понимаю, что есть физическая память, виртуальная память системы и виртуальное адресное пространство самого процесса? Если да, значит ли это, что обладая достаточными привилегиями процесс B может найти в виртуальной памяти системы адреса блоков выделенных для процесса А, и с помощью этих адресов "собрать" все что находится в адресном пространстве процесса А, "без его ведома"?

Comment: `Значит ли это, что обладая достаточными привилегиями...` — для этого надо быть драйвером, потому что Windows хранит таблицы отображений в памяти ядра, куда обычным приложениям доступа нет.

Comment: @Arhad Но концепцию я понимаю правильно? Драйвером - любым или каким то определенным? И вообще не могли бы вы что нибудь посоветовать почитать про ring0 и т.п., потому как то, что я вычитал в интернете как то не "уложилось по полочкам".

Comment: `Драйвером - любым или каким то определенным` — любым. По своей сути, любой драйвер — это динамическая библиотека, загружаемая в привилегированную память ядра. То есть драйвер даже не обязан уметь работать с каким-либо устройством.

Comment: `И вообще не могли бы вы что нибудь посоветовать почитать` — могу посоветовать два хороших ресурса по разработке ОС, http://wiki.osdev.org/ (на английском) и http://ru.osdev.wikia.com/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F (на русском). А так, что именно вам непонятно? Кольца защиты (Ring 0-3) — это просто список разрешённых инструкций процессора. К примеру, инструкция `lgdt` (переопределить обработчики прерываний процессора) разрешена только в Ring 0 (наиболее привилегированном), чтобы программы не угробили многозадачность перехватом прерываний таймера в обход операционной системы.